# Im trying to use OpenHardwareMonitor source code but never get my video card temperature what could be wrong?

Tags: c#

In form1 i did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;

namespace NvidiaTemp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            computer.Open();
            var temps = new List<decimal>();
            foreach (var hardware in computer.Hardware)
            {
                if (hardware.HardwareType != HardwareType.CPU)
                    continue;
                hardware.Update();
                foreach (var sensor in hardware.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType != SensorType.Temperature)
                    {
                        if (sensor.Value != null)
                            temps.Add((decimal)sensor.Value);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (decimal temp in temps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
                MessageBox.Show(temp.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();




        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Its never get in to the foreach jump over it.
Tried so many samples examples cant figure out how ot make it work. And im sure my video card support it since if im running the origiran openhardwaremonitor program ikts howing all parameters like temepratures and speeds...

Just downloaded the openhwardwaremonitor.dll file from the official program website:

http://openhardwaremonitor.org/downloads/
the dll is in the directory of the program it self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I broke out [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx) and took a look at the example exe that ships with the download, as the documentation is quite rudimentary - which is often the case :-)

I noticed that when the `Computer` object is initialized, the boolean properties like `GPUEnabled` are set to true.

So...

```
Computer myComputer = new Computer();

myComputer.Open();

myComputer.GPUEnabled = true; //This is the line you are missing.

foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
{

    if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
    {
        foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
        {
            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The current temperature is {0}", sensor.Value));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I run that code from a Windows Forms app on my machine, I get the current temperature (38C, which means I'm obviously not running it hard enough!)

If I do not set GPUEnabled, I get exactly the same result as you - no items in the `IHardware` collection.

**UPDATE:**

To answer the other question you posed in the comments, an example like the following should work for you:

```
    Timer timer;

    Computer myComputer;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();



        myComputer = new Computer();

        myComputer.Open();

        myComputer.GPUEnabled = true;

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();

     }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
        {

            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The current temperature is {0}", sensor.Value));
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Here we have a `Windows.Forms.Timer` and the `Computer` class as class level variables which we initialize in the constructor. Every 5 seconds, the `tick` event will fire, enumerating the hardware, and displaying a message box with the current temp in. This could easily be a label, and you could even store the `Sensor` in a class level variable to avoid enumerating the `IHardware` collection each time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Dash its working im running openhardwaremonitor in the same time and the gpu temperature are the saem. Just what did you mean you are not running it hard enough ? Do you mean the temperature is low 38c since you dont make your pc to work hard enough ?

Comment: Yup - I was being lighthearted - I obviously need to play more Crysis to get the GPU to run hotter :-) It's still running about 6C hotter than my CPU though.

Comment: Another question Dash how can i make it to show me the temeperatue every 1second or 5seconds i mean to update it every X seconds ? I will update my question with the code i did now i added a timer but it dosent update it its showing it only once.

Comment: Dash anyway i took the code in the contructor like you did but leave the computer varaible instance and the computer variable enable and also did timer enable there and in the timer tick event put all the foreach but still not updating the temperature.

Comment: You are best raising that as a new question because it's significantly different from your new question. Also, it's actually a more generic question so you'll find that more people will answer it (and point you at similar questions).

Comment: @user1544479 I updated my answer with an example. I suggest you take a look at this as it should do what you want, but do feel free to raise a new question.