# Update a TextBox every n seconds with an output from the OpenHardwareMonitor library

Tags: c#

For now its showing the temperature once.
I want it to work like in openhardwaremonitor original program that the temperature change/update every each second or according to if there is any change in the temperatures im not sure how it work there.

What i did is took out all the foreach loops from the constructor and put it in a timer tick event. But it dosent work. In openhardwaremonitor its showing changed to 51c while in my application its all the time on 44c as it was in the first time i ran the application.

I used a breakpoint on the textBox line and sometimes its getting there sometimes its just doing the inner loop but dosent pass the if and dosent get to the messagebox and if it does get to the messagebox its still showing 44c .

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;

namespace NvidiaTemp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Computer computer = new Computer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            computer.Open();
            computer.GPUEnabled = true;
            timer1.Enabled = true;





        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var hardwareItem in computer.Hardware)
            {

                if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
                {
                    foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                    {
                        if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                        {
                            //   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The current temperature is {0}", sensor.Value));
                            textBox1.Text = String.Format("The current temperature is {0}", sensor.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Why it dosent update it dosent get to the textBox line each time its doing the loop ?
2. Does it updating the temperature onlt if there is a change in the temperature value or its working with a timer in the openhardwaremonitor original program ?

Comment: *hint*: use linq instead of nested for each.
Also ... Sorry man, but I really can't understand what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually posted a partial answer to this on your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749306/im-trying-to-use-openhardwaremonitor-source-code-but-never-get-my-video-card-tem), but include it here for reference.

Your question is actually mostly just a standard question about Windows.Forms.Timer (or you could even use a BackgroundWorker or any other timer you chose to with the usual caveat of checking InvokeRequired)

Anyway, the following is a short example of something that should work for you:

```
    Timer timer;

    Computer myComputer;

    ISensor GPUTemperatureSensor;

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        myComputer = new Computer();

        myComputer.Open();

        myComputer.GPUEnabled = true;

        foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
        {

            if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
            {
                foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                {
                    if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                    {
                        GPUTemperatureSensor = sensor;

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();

     }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(GPUTemperatureSensor != null)
        {
            GPUTemperatureSensor.Hardware.Update();//This line refreshes the sensor values
            textBox1.Text = String.Format("The current temperature is {0}", GPUTemperatureSensor.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Could not find the GPU Temperature Sensor. Stopping.";
            timer.Stop(); 
        }
    }
```

I've actually stored the Sensor at the class level to avoid enumerating the hardware collection everytime.

I have also included @mikez comment for the Update() method on the hardware - thanks Mike!

Comment: Ahhh... take a look at my first example again - I've declared a class level variable called `ISensor GPUTemperatureSensor` - in the Constructor, we assign this variable to the GPU Temperature Sensor and then we can use it in all non static methods in the form...

Comment: Dash i tried now your first code replaces in the textBox line sensor with GPUTemperatureSensor.Value so no errors i run it and its showing the temp first time but it dosent update it. Its all the time on the first temp 45c.

Comment: Dash did it work at your place ? did the temp change every 5 seconds or so ?

Comment: I never tested it that far; the thing to do would be to run another program (like a game that's graphically intensive), and then ALT-TAB out of that to see if the temperature value has gone up. If it hasn't, then it's really a question for the author of the library.

Comment: I took a look at the source, which is available here: http://code.google.com/p/open-hardware-monitor/ . It appears you need to call the `Update` method on the sensor's hardware. Something like `GPUTemperatureSensor.Hardware.Update()`.

Comment: Dash second code is working i just needed to add : sensor.Hardware.Update(); before the textBox1.Text line changed the timer interval to 1000 wich is second each time. Working like the original openhardwaremonitor program. Thank you.

Comment: Mike z indeed for the updating i used the sensor.Hardware.Update(); Thank you.

Comment: @mikez Good spot - thanks for the comment, have updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are doing it in the loop.  I would guess that this is causing a problem because if the loop hasn't completed before the next tick they might be stepping on each other.

Assuming there is only 1 GPU and 1 Temperature sensor in that GPU, why not do something like this:

```
var hardwareItem = computer.Hardware.Single(h => h.HardwareType == HardwareType.GpuNvidia)
var sensor = hardwareItem.Sensors.Single(s => s.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
//   MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The current temperature is {0}", sensor.Value));
textBox1.Text = String.Format("The current temperature is {0}", sensor.Value);
```

You will totally remove unnecessary loops and should make that method run fast.

Comment: There's nothing in the OP's post about needing loops.  I'm just not sure why loops are needed to pull 1 object out of the list of hardware, then 1 sensor out of that list.

Comment: It's just enumerating the list of hardware everytime - it was some example code; your code is a neater contraction of the enumeration as the .Single will still enumerate items - it just returns on the first GpuNvidia item so it doesn't necessarily traverse all items. It's possible for Hardware to be filled with lots of different types of hardware.

Comment: Jeff you're correct.. but I read it as he was wanting a list of harware based on the loop once again ambiguous problem description ...LOL